# mmap() of arrays or malloced memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, mmap

I am trying to find the memory map of an array or some memory allocated from malloc() using mmap() but it is showing invalid argument.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int *var1=NULL;
        size_t size=0;

        size = 1000*sizeof(int);

        var1 = (int*)malloc(size);



        int i=0;

        for(i=0;i<999;i++)
        {
                var1[i] = 1;
        }


        printf("%p\n",var1);
        void *addr=NULL;

        addr = mmap((void *)var1, size, PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);         //to create memory map of var1

        err(1,NULL);    //to print error

        return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
a.out: Invalid argument
```

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Proximate cause**: `mmap` fails because you asked it do create a new memory mapping, you asked for the mapping to be placed at a specific address (`var1`'s address), that address is already occupied (by the heap from which `malloc` got its memory), and you told the operating system it was not allowed to choose an alternate address in case `var1` was not a suitable address (`MAP_FIXED`).

**Analysis**: What are you trying to do here? What does "find the memory map of an array" mean? Do you want to have your array of integers located in heap memory (returned by `malloc()`) or in an anonymous memory mapping created by `mmap()`? By the way, unless you `fork()` (create a child process) there is little functional difference: both are areas of memory that are private to your process. But they are not the same thing and you can't manipulate the heap with `mmap()` nor can you manage mapped memory with `malloc()`.

Comment: actually I want to further use the mapping in madivse() to mark the memory as mergeable.
So if you could help me to mark some malloced memory as mergeable using madvise(). 
Please help me.

Comment: Read the `madvise` man page. It says "KSM only merges private anonymous pages (see `mmap(2)`)". You got your memory block from `malloc`. It is not a private anonymous page. It does not fit the requirement for using `madvise(MADV_MERGEABLE)`. End of story.